# Get all rows from table whose key isn't matched in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called **products** and a table called **product_description**
They both have a column called **product_id** which is used to link them.
How do I get all the rows from the **product_description** table whose **product_id** is
not found in the products table?

I tried this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM `product_description` 
JOIN product ON product_description.product_id = product.product_id
WHERE product_description.product_id != product.product_id
```

But that returned zero rows.

Comment: Regardless of the `left join` you are missing, you seem to have a referential integrity issue: How can you have product descriptions that don't have a product?

Comment: Because Im modifying tables from an old system to be moved into a new system and the old system is messed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a left outer join and find where there are no matches:

```
SELECT product_description.* 
FROM `product_description` left outer join product
      on product_description.product_id = product.product_id
where product.product_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

`INNER JOIN` filters out mismatches. That's why you don't get any results with your query. What you need is an `OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT * 
  FROM product_description d LEFT JOIN product p
    ON d.product_id = p.product_id
 WHERE p.product_id IS NULL
```

or you can use a subquery with `NOT IN`

```
SELECT * 
  FROM product_description 
 WHERE product_id NOT IN
(
  SELECT product_id 
    FROM product
)
```

or with `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT * 
  FROM product_description d
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT * 
    FROM product
   WHERE product_id = d.product_id
)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe6830/2)** demo for all above-mentioned queries

To better understand `JOIN`s see [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: `NOT IN` and `null` values don't get along see this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07682/1). There is not enough information to assume there are no null values in there, particularly after having this referential integrity issue.

Comment: @MostyMostacho It's a common fact and like you said there is not enough information but one can assume that `product_id` is a PK and yes there is a way to re-write it null safe way http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07682/2. But thanks for the input anyway.